# Multiple constructors poco with Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a POCO that used to get properly populated with EF

```
public class CompanyToggle
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; } // CompanyId (Primary key)
    public int ToggleId { get; private set; } // ToggleId (Primary key)
    public bool IsEnabled { get; private set; } // IsEnabled

    // Foreign keys

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent Company pointed by [CompanyToggle].([CompanyId]) (FK_CompanyToggle_Company)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Company Company { get; private set; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent Toggle pointed by [CompanyToggle].([ToggleId]) (FK_CompanyToggle_Toggle)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Toggle Toggle { get; private set; }

    // For EF
    private CompanyToggle()
    { }
}
```

Then I added another Ctor:

```
public CompanyToggle(Guid companyId, int toggleId, bool isEnabled)
    {
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        this.ToggleId = toggleId;
        this.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
```

And my Fluent API binding is like this:

```
public class CompanyToggleConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyToggle>
{
    public CompanyToggleConfiguration()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public CompanyToggleConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("CompanyToggle", schema);
        HasKey(x => new { x.CompanyId, x.ToggleId });

        Property(x => x.CompanyId).HasColumnName(@"CompanyId").HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(x => x.ToggleId).HasColumnName(@"ToggleId").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(x => x.IsEnabled).HasColumnName(@"IsEnabled").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();

        // Foreign keys
        HasRequired(a => a.Company).WithMany(b => b.CompanyToggles).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // FK_CompanyToggle_Company
        HasRequired(a => a.Toggle).WithMany(b => b.CompanyToggles).HasForeignKey(c => c.ToggleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // FK_CompanyToggle_Toggle
    }
}
```

After adding the new public Ctor, loading objects from context loads only `CompanyId` and `ToggleId`, and leaves both Toggle and Company objects nulls.

I could fix it by making CompanyToggle parameterless Ctor to public, but I'd like to keep it private.

Any idea why this behavior from EF? Looks to me as EF is looking for the most accessible Ctor!

Comment: You've got fluent code so don't you mean Code First?

Comment: Also, your nav properties are virtual so will be lazy loaded. You need to explicitly load the children: `var companyToggleList = context.CompanyToggle.Include(c => c.Toggle).Include(c => c.Company).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene! I was missing the Include!